# IBM Message Broker Toolkit 6.1

Tags: eclipse-plugin, messagebroker

Is it possible to change Eclipse under the IBM Message Broker Toolkit 6.1?
I need a newer version of it to use TFS plugin.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported to modify the version of eclipse that the toolkit is running on.